# Arrays and if statements

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement

Can somebody please help me with the `if` statement and arrays. So for example I type in `0001` in the array `"1"` is `[3]`. I'm trying to get it to print `"working"` if `1` is typed on array `[3]`.

This code should explain it more:

```
original = raw_input("Type is your input? ")
original_as_array = list(original)
print original_as_array
print original[3]

if (original[3] == 1):
    print "working"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are comparing an `int` with a single character (type `str`). Change your `if`-statement to:

```
if (original[3] == "1"):
    print "working"
```

and it will work.

Your input from the key consists of characters (`'0001'`), so your comparison has to take that into account.

E.g.,

```
type(original[3])
str

type(1)
int
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, strings are already arrays so you do not need to convert them into lists.
In Python a string doesn't compare equal to an integer, so you should be comparing to `'1'` instead. Lastly, the if statement looks better without the brackets :D

```
>>> original = raw_input("Type is your input? ")
Type is your input? 0001
>>> if original[3] == '1':
        print "working"


working
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are checking an int against a str, which will be False. See this interactive session:

```
>>> original = raw_input("Type is your input? ")
Type is your input? 0001
>>> original_as_array = list(original)
>>> print original_as_array
['0', '0', '0', '1']
>>> print original[3]
1
>>> if original[3] == 1:
...     print "working"
... 
>>> print type(original[3])
<type 'str'>
>>> if original[3] == '1':
...     print "working"
... 
working
>>>
```